# My bootstrap modal doesn't close after pressing button

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

Here's my modal component: `

```
<div class="modal-content my-custom-modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Dodawanie żartu</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="adding-joke">
      <form method="POST" [formGroup]="addJokeForm" (ngSubmit)="addJoke()">
        <div class="joke-category">
          <select name="group" class="custom-select" formControlName="category">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Wybierz kategorię</option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of categories">{{ category.name }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="joke-content">
          <input placeholder="Wprowadź treść" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="content">
        </div>
        <div class="cancel-joke">
          <button type="button" class="cancel-button" (click)="cancelJoke()">Anuluj</button>
        </div>
        <div class="add-joke">
          <button class="add-button" id="add_joke_button">
            Dodaj
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

and my typescript:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { PagesService } from '../pages.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbActiveModal] // Dodaj dostawcę
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  public jokes: any = [];
  modalRef?: NgbModalRef;
  public categories: any = [];
  addJokeForm!: FormGroup;
  get addJokeF() { return this.addJokeForm.controls; }

  @Input() src: any;
  @Output() jokeAdded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private pagesService: PagesService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addJokeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      content: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.loadCategories();
  }

  loadCategories() {
    this.pagesService.LoadCategories().subscribe(response => {
      this.categories = response;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  addJoke() {
    if (this.addJokeForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      const json_data = {
        category: this.addJokeF['category'].value,
        content: this.addJokeF['content'].value,
      };
      this.pagesService.AddJoke(json_data).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
       // this.jokeAdded.emit(response);
       // this.activeModal.close('jokeAdded');
      });
    }
  }

  cancelJoke() {
    this.activeModal.dismiss('cancelled');
  }
}
```

I tried to do :
<button type="button" class="cancel-button" (click)="modalRef?.dismiss()">Anuluj
Nothing work, laso I don't have any errors in my console so maybe someone has any idea?
I would like to close this modal after pressing button. Also tried: (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')"

Comment: Did you check if the `cancelJoke()` method is called properly? You can add a `console.log` statement inside the function to check if it is being executed when the button is clicked. Also, double-check that you are correctly using the `app-modal` component in your application template and passing the necessary data and functions.